# How to show the joint weak convergence?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limit-theorems

Given a $T>0$, let $\mathcal{C}[0,T]$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,T]$. Let $Y_n(t)$ be stochastic processes in $\mathcal{C}[0,T]$. We define the weak convergence in the sense of uniform metric and denote it as "$\Rightarrow$", see Billingsley (1968) *Convergence of Probability Measures*, Chapter 2.

Suppose we have the joint convergence
$$
(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow (X,c) \quad \text{as} \quad n\to\infty, 
$$
where $X_n$ and $X$ are random variables, $Y_n\in\mathcal{C}[0,T]$ and $c$ is a "constant" process.

Can we prove that
$$
(X_n,Z_n)\Rightarrow(X,Z) \quad \text{as} \quad n\to\infty, 
$$
where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion being independent of $X_n$, $Z_n(t)=\int_0^t Y_n(s){\rm d}B(s)$ are stochastic integrals ($Y_n$ is adapted to the filtration generated by $B$), and $Z(t)=cB(t)$.

Notice that, the weak convergence theory of stochastic integrals do show that $Z_n\Rightarrow Z$, but I don't find an answer for the above joint weak convergence.

Could you provide a detailed proof ? Or provide a counter-example ?

Thank you !

Comment: well it depends on the type of weak-convergence you have for the field $Y_{n}(t)$. Is it for each fixed $t$? Is it uniformly eg. over Skorokhod topology or over some supremum norm? Even in a deterministic setting you can have pointwise convergence but not L1.

Comment: For convergence theorems for Itô integrals, there are many results in a)Revuz-Yor, b)Stroock-Varadhan and c)the Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes book by Jacod-Shiryaev

Comment: in your post , can you explicitly write mathematically what you mean in the weak convergence uniform metric?

Comment: @ThomasKojar In their results, they do prove the weak convergence for Ito integrals, i.e., $Z_n\Rightarrow Z$. But I can't find an answer for the joint weak convergence.

Comment: @ThomasKojar I edit the question.

Comment: @MikeHWANG : To have the stochastic integrals $Z_n(t)$ defined, you need to assume that the processes $Y_n$ are adapted to the filtration generated by the Brownian motion.

Comment: @IosifPinelis added this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\CC}{\mathcal C}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$For any real $\ep>0$, let
\begin{equation*}
    Y_{n,\ep}(t):=\min(c+\ep,\max(c-\ep,Y_n(t)); 
\end{equation*}
here and else where, $t\in[0,T]$.
Then the process $Y_{n,\ep}$ is adapted to the filtration generated by $B$. So, we can introduce
\begin{equation*}
    Z_{n,\ep}(t):=\int_0^t Y_{n,\ep}(s)\,dB(s)  
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    D_{n,\ep}(t):=Z_{n,\ep}(t)-Z(t)=\int_0^t (Y_{n,\ep}(s)-c)\,dB(s).   
\end{equation*}
Then $D_{n,\ep}$ is a martingale and hence $D_{n,\ep}^2$ is a nonnegative submartingale. So, for any real $\de>0$, by the Doob martingale inequality and the Itô isometry, denoting by $\|\cdot\|$ the norm in $\CC[0,T]$, we have
\begin{equation*}   
\begin{aligned}
    P(\|Z_n-Z\|>\de,\|Y_n-c\|\le\ep)&\le P(\|D_{n,\ep}\|>\de) \\ 
    &=P(\max_{t\in[0,T]}D_{n,\ep}(t)^2>\de^2) \\ 
    &\le\frac{ED_{n,\ep}(T)^2}{\de^2} \\ 
    &=\frac1{\de^2}\,\int_0^T E((Y_{n,\ep}(s)-c)^2\,dt \\ 
    &\le\frac{\ep^2 T}{\de^2}\le\de 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
if $\ep^2\le T\de^3$.

Also, the condition $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow(X,c)$ implies $Y_n\Rightarrow c$ and hence $Y_n\to c$ in probability, so that $P(\|Y_n-c\|>\ep)\to0$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \limsup_n P(\|Z_n-Z\|>\de)\le\limsup_n P(\|Z_n-Z\|>\de,\|Y_n-c\|\le\ep)+\lim_n P(\|Y_n-c\|>\ep)
    \le\de+0
\end{equation*}
for any real $\de>0$.

So, $Z_n\to Z$ in probability and hence $Z_n\Rightarrow Z$. So, for any real $\de>0$ and some compact $K_{Z,\de}$ in $\CC[0,T]$ and all $n$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    P(Z_n\notin K_{Z,\de})+P(Z\notin K_{Z,\de})\le\de.
\end{equation*}
Similarly, the condition $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow(X,c)$ implies $X_n\Rightarrow X$ and hence for some compact $K_{X,\de}$ in $\R$ and all $n$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    P(X_n\notin K_{X,\de})\le\de.
\end{equation*}

Now take any bounded (say by $1$) continuous function $f\colon\R\times\CC[0,T]$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $K_{X,\de}\times K_{Z,\de}$. So, for each real $\ep>0$ there is some real $\de>0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &E|f(X_n,Z_n)-f(X_n,Z)|\,1(\{(X_n,Z_n),(X_n,Z)\}\subseteq K_{X,\de}\times K_{Z,\de}) \\ 
    &\le\ep+2P(\|Z_n-Z\|>\de)\to\ep. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation}
    \limsup_n E|f(X_n,Z_n)-f(X_n,Z)|\le\ep+2P(Z_n\notin K_{Z,\de})+2P(Z\notin K_{Z,\de})
    +2P(X_n\notin K_{X,\de})\le\ep+4\de. 
\end{equation}
Also, because $X_n\Rightarrow X$ and $X_n$ is independent of $B$ and hence of $Z$, we have $Ef(X_n,Z)\to Ef(X,Z)$.

Thus, $Ef(X_n,Z_n)\to Ef(X,Z)$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @MikeHWANG : Thank you for your appreciation. Are you satisfied with the answer?